# How can I get my library code to recompile if the application environment changes?

Tags: elixir

I'm writing an Elixir library whose behavior depends largely on a user-supplied dictionary file. I process the file at compile time, like this:

```
defmodule SomeModule do
  @dictionary Application.get_env(:some_lib, :dictionary_file) 
    |> do_some_processing

  ...
end
```

A parent project can specify which dictionary file to use in their `config.exs`:

```
config :some_lib, dictionary_file: "/path/to/dictionary.txt"
```

If the parent project's owner modifies their `config.exs` to specify a different `dictionary_file`, my module needs to be recompiled. However, right now, not only does this not happen automatically, it doesn't even happen if I run `mix deps.compile --force` in the parent project.

Elixir supplies [`@external_resource`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Module.html) to express "recompile my code if a certain external file changes". But I don't see a way to say "recompile my code if the application environment changes".

How can I do this?

Comment: I should note - I've only tried my library as a local dependency so far. I'm not sure if that affects the behavior of `mix deps.compile`.

Answer (score 1):

## A Workaround

Instead of having my library module use the environment directly, I can do this: make the parent application define a module that uses their environment. Instead of using `LibraryModule.do_stuff()`, they will call `ParentProjectModule.do_stuff()`.

Eg:

```
defmodule ParentProjectModule do
  @dictionary Application.get_env(:some_lib, :dictionary_file) 
    |> do_some_processing

  use LibraryModule
end
```

Then I can do:

```
defmodule LibraryModule
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      # define all my functions, using @dictionary as needed
    end
  end
end
```

When the parent application environment changes, their module is recompiled, so the library functions behave accordingly.